# Subtract on Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I wanted to subtract all CR with DR row for each account no separately.

Expected output :

### account_no |   REMIT

10051056346  |   7,04,215
10051059074  |   9,39,395

Comment: please provide a minimal example as **text** (images are not helpful) and the matching expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) selector:

```
out = (df
 .xs('CR', level='type')
 .sub(df.xs('DR', level='type'))
)
```

Comment: Getting an error with this . (TypeError: Index must be a MultiIndex)

Comment: @HarshMishra in the shown image, there is a MultiIndex. I cannot guess what your data really is without a reproducible example.